# How to create "Dynamic" Breadcrumbs in Zend Navigation

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation

With Zend_Navigation, I can do something like

```
Home > Projects > Collaborators
```

but What if I want something more useful

```
Home > Project name > Collaborator name
```

How can I acheive this? Is it a good idea? Possibly, there would be performance issues? Cos it got to query up the hierarchy? But whatever it is, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example #34 shows you how to use a view partial for breadcrumbs. I'd do a `foreach` on `$this->pages` and adjust where needed

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.navigation.breadcrumbs

Comment: +1. I think this is the easiest way of doing this. Another way  would be to directly play with your navigation container, but  it is more complicated that what Ashley suggests and unnecessary in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to render the breadcrumbs and then append to this string the Collaborator name.

This works unless you don't need it in the navigation or sitemap. Otherwise, you have to add it to the *container* manually.

```
$this->navigation()
  ->getContainer()
  ->findOneByLabel('Colaborators')
  ->addPage(array('label'=>'name', 'uri'=>'/name'));
```

Comment: This really helped with creating a dynamic sitemap for one of my sites. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a little bit late, but since I've been struggling with this, I'm posting it just in case it can help anyone.

If you just want to change the actual label of the current page, the easiest way to do it is in this way:

```
$this->view->navigation()->findOneByRoute(
                              Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
                                                     ->getRouter()
                                                     ->getCurrentRouteName()
                           )
                        ->setLabel($label);
```

The *findOneByRoute* will work charmly if you use Zend_Routes, if you don't, you can change it by *findOneByX*, being X is any property of the page.

Answering to the question of the OP, in this case, it would be easy to do:

```
$this->view->navigation()->findOneByLabel('Collaborators')
                         ->setLabel('Collaborator'. $name);
```

Being $name, the name of the collaborator.

I hope this helps to those people that still use ZF1.

Greetings,